# Convert Images to Video in Android

Tags: javacv

I Successfully convert images to video in android by using ffmpeg, javacv
now i want to add background music on video.
Below code convert images to video but cannot find audio

```
public void imagevideo(ArrayList<String> links)
{

    Log.d("Received",""+links);

        iplimage = new opencv_core.IplImage[links.size()];
       for (int j = 0; j < links.size(); j++) 
       {
       System.out.println(" j " + "Inise Loop"+links.get(j).toString());
       iplimage[j]=cvLoadImage(links.get(j));


     }
```

here is get image array length
           Log.d("Length",""+iplimage.length);
        Frame framee;
           File videopath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test");
           videopath.mkdirs();

```
    String audioFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/susic.mp3"; 


         try {



            FFmpegFrameGrabber audioFrames = FFmpegFrameGrabber.createDefault(audioFile);
            FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test/video.mp4",400,400,audioFrames.getAudioChannels());

             Log.d("Enter in Try","FF");               
             Log.d("Start Recorder","");
             Log.d("Length","Sound Grab");
             audioFrames.start();

             recorder.setFrameRate(30);
             recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
             recorder.setVideoBitrate(9000);
             recorder.setFormat("mp4");
             recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
             recorder.setSampleRate(44100);
             recorder.setVideoQuality(0); // maximum quality
             recorder.start();

             Frame frame=null;

             Log.d("Length",""+iplimage.length);
            for (int i=0;i< iplimage.length;i++)
            {   
                frame=audioFrames.grabFrame();

                   long t = 9000 * (System.currentTimeMillis());
                   if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                       recorder.setTimestamp(t);

                       recorder.record(iplimage[i]);
                        recorder.record(frame); 




               }

            }
             recorder.stop();




}
```